# Can i add video clip to asset bundle in unity?

Tags: assetbundle

I am working on AR application in unity engine and i have a huge amount of video clips somy problem is that how can I add them into AssetsBundle so I can reduce the size of Application, or there is any other way to Manage them ?

Comment: Could you find an answer to this? Can you load videos from assetbundles on iOS? In android it works now as long as it has no compression, but what about iOS?

Comment: I don't have idea about it. is it really possible to load video in assets bundle for android platform? can you send me some link to study it

Comment: Has there been any update? This seems incredibly complicated for simple video playback.